# Java script - invoice due date miscalculation

Tags: javascript, date

Apologies in advance for my (something less than) basic knowledge of java script.

Can someone explain in basic – but specific – terms how this script is calculating?

Here is the script:

```
var d = new Date(year, month, day);
var e = new Date(d.getTime() + offset * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var month_out = e.getUTCMonth();
var day_out = e.getDate();
var year_out = e.getUTCFullYear();
date_out = month_out + "-" + day_out + "-" + year_out;


year = 2013
month = 12
day = 01
offset = 15
```

The offset is the “payment terms” and the date is the invoice date.  The output is supposed to be the invoice date plus the offset to arrive at “12-16-2013”

That is NOT what it is kicking out and I need to figure out how to fix it.
One customer is having dates show up as:  0-16-2014

I don’t know which string is wrong or how it should read in its place. This is one piece of an entire function that pulls an invoice date from an XML file, strips the time from the date and creates a new "Date_Due" using the offset. This script is the only area that is failing.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You should use `e.getUTCDate()` as well, otherwise the day part will be in the user's local timezone while the rest is in UTC

Answer (score 1):

`getUTCMonth()` returns 0 based months - 0 is January, 1 is February, etc.

Add 1 to this value to make it more human readable.

See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMonth) for more info.

Comment: Similarly, the [constructor for Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) expects the month to be from 0..11, so subtract one from the month on your first line.